# Trying to get -Identity value from Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I know the best practice is to use property values such as `Name`, `Distinguishedname` etc. However, I am working with two systems and the only field in Active Directory which is the same in both systems is `extensionAttribute1`. Below is the code. The error is with the `foreach` loop and not accepting the variable for `-Identity`.

```
Function ArchiveLeavers
{
Write-Host "Archiving leavers. Details below..."

$csvLeavers = Import-Csv -Path $fileLeavers      

    foreach ($user in $csvLeavers)
    {

    $csvID = $user.ExtensionAttribute1

    if (Get-ADUser -filter {extensionAttribute1 -eq $csvID} -SearchBase $LeaverOU)
    {
        Write-Host ($user.GivenName + ' ' + $user.LastName) " is already in leavers"
    }

    else
    {
        ForEach-Object  
        {
        $identity = Get-ADUser -filter {extensionAttribute1 -eq $csvID} | select distinguishedName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders

        write-host ($user.GivenName + ' ' + $user.LastName) " needs moving"
        Move-ADObject -Identity $identity -TargetPath $LeaverOU;
        Set-ADUser    -Add @{extensionAttribute7=$user.ExtensionAttribute7}
        Write-Host ($user.GivenName + ' ' + $user.LastName) " has been moved"
        }

    }
  }
}
```

This is the Error:

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 
    'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified 
    method is not supported.
    At line:21 char:57
    +Move-ADObject -Identity $identity -TargetPath $F ...
    +~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

Comment: Don't use Format-list/-table with variable assignments. They are only for formatting an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Format-Table which convert your `$Identity` variable to object which is not known by `Move-ADObject` which get only input kind of SAM,Guid,SID etc.

Remove the Format-Table from the pipe, Change this:

```
$identity = Get-ADUser -filter {extensionAttribute1 -eq $csvID} | select distinguishedName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

To this:

```
$identity = Get-ADUser -filter {extensionAttribute1 -eq $csvID}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is my fault for over complicating things.... Working perfectly now.